# I'm trying to make an "ENTER" button that takes you to a hidden page on a website, once you submit a password

Tags: javascript, html, css

The website has been created using GoDaddy website builder so my options for how I do this are limited, however I just want to create password only access (can be the same password for everyone) to one of the pages, with an input field for the password and a submit button.

I am a total beginner and trying to teach myself (probably obvious!).  I have cobbled together the following with very little knowledge and am obviously doing something wrong.

```js
function passWord() {
  
  var testV = 1;
  var pass1 = prompt('Please Enter Your Password', '');
  
  while (testV < 3) {
    if (!pass1)
      history.go(-1);
    
    if (pass1.toLowerCase() == "mypassword") {
      window.open('http://www.website.com/webpage.html');
      break;
    }
    
    testV += 1;
    
    var pass1 =
      prompt('Access Denied - Password Incorrect, Please Try Again.', '');
  
  }
  
  if (pass1.toLowerCase() != "password" & testV == 3)
    history.go(-1);
  
  return " ";

}
```

```css
input {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Style the submit button */

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: white;
}


/* The message box is shown when the user clicks on the password field */

#message {
  display: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#message p {
  padding: 10px 35px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="password" id="pwd" name="pwd" <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: An important thing to remember is that JavaScript is run in the browser, and **everything in the browser is in the user's control**. If you put this on a page, the user can use the "View Source" or "Debug Tools" in their browser to see 1) what the correct password is; and 2) what the "secret" URL is so that they can go there without running the JS at all.

Comment: As for your actual problem, you've defined a function called "passWord", but don't seem to ever be calling it - your form submits to a PHP page (which would actually be a better place to put the password logic).

Comment: Not sure how far along the website is but I'd start over with Wordpress. It's a far better CMS than any hosting company's website builder, you can keep your website even if you switch from GoDaddy to another host, and it supports password-protected pages out of the box.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the location API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

change -> `window.open('http://www.website.com/webpage.html');`

to `location.assign("http://www.website.com/webpage.html")`

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I'm tearing my hair out!  I know its not ideal to set it up this way but at least to begin with it is not a big problem if other users can see the password.  If someone can just help me complete this as it is I would be incredibly grateful

Comment: Don’t delete and re-post answers just to clear downvotes